# rspec - redirect to Group.last going to wrong record

Tags: testing, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

39 tests pass but 1 fails.

> ```
> Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/groups/11> 
> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/groups/12>
> ```

I create a new record and try to redirect to `show` it but I'm one record 'off'.

Looks like some kinda caching / reload issue perhaps?

My rspec test:

```
describe "POST #create" do

  ...

  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new group" do
      expect{
        post :create, group: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:group)
      }.to change(Group,:count).by(1)
    end

    it "redirects to the new group" do
      post :create, group: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:group)
      response.should redirect_to Group.last
    end
  end

  ...
```

My Code:

```
  # POST /groups
  # POST /groups.xml
  def create
    @group = Group.new(params[:group])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Group was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@group) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @group, :status => :created, :location => @group }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @group.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The result:

The count changes (that test passes) but the the direct foes to the **last** record, i.e. I get:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to Group.last
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/groups/11> 
   but was a redirect to <http://test.host/groups/12>
```

Comment: Rails 3.2.4 has an odd bug a bit like that - if you are using 3.2.4 have you tried 3.2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that the model (Group) has order by group name as a default scope.

The fix was just to use `Group.unscoped.last` in the test !